# How to implement interface dependent on Action and Func? Action implementation returns nothing while Func returns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter, strategy-pattern

I need to implement an interface to implement strategy pattern in C#.

One step would be to `CreateRetryInvocationContext` and second would be to execute.

Second step can be of two types ) i.e. `Func` or `Action`. Retry operation could return a value or might returns void.

So, I already have two concrete implementation for this  ( i.e. `RetryOperationWithResult` and `RetryOperarationWithoutResult` ). Both of implementations are implementing 'Execute' method. But the problem is WithResult needs to return and other one dont need. How can I persue with this? Which way I can arrange interfaces to have better orchestration and less burden on client side. Kind of balanced and well testable implementation on both ends.

Here is my proposed Class hierarchy :

```
 public class RetryOperationWithResult<T> : IRetryProcessor<T>
{
    private Func<List<object>, T> _action;

    public RetryOperationWithResult(Func<List<object>, T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public T Execute(RetryOperationContext retryOpContext)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        try
        {
            //Retry logic 
            //
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and the other for `Action` implementation. Of course following doesn't get compiled.

```
class RetryOperationWithOutResult : IRetryProcessor<void>
{
     public void Execute(RetryOperationContext retryOpContext)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

Comment: `Action` and `Func` are unrelated types, so unifying them probably isn't a good idea. What are you trying to achieve here? Reuse the retry logic for both types?

Comment: Yes, Trying copy re-use logic on both separate implementation. One without result and other with result.  So, both logic are part of separate implementations.  But I want strategy pattern to implement and thats why only wana expose one mthod of interface 'Execute'. But either this has to return or not have to return anything.

Comment: As you cannot change return types when overriding, overloading may be a better option, with the retry logic in a private method.

Comment: actually i also have to create the proper context before calling of the concrete implementation ( providing the action arguments, providing post retry method also included ), So I want to make the client calls much simpler and offload the whole heavy retry thing to their seperate implementations orchestrating by interface called by clients.